# Extract String Between First and Second Whitespace

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning, stringr

I'm trying to extract a certain portion of the text in a column - I only want the text between the first and second whitespace - in this case the manufacture year.  The field is in column "Detail" within the dataframe "data".  This is the structure which is consistent:

**Used 2014 Toyota Camry**

I'm only interested in capturing the "2014" within this field:

Here is what I've tried:

```
sub(".*?\\s+(.*)\\s.*", "\\1", "Used 2014 Toyota Camry", perl=TRUE)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, you also need to limit your capture group.

```
sub(".*?\\s+(.*?)\\s.*", "\\1", "Used 2014 Toyota Camry")
#[1] "2014"
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I think if we don't make the first asterisk lazy it still works.

Answer (score 1):

If that's only first and second white space, this solution can also be used:

```
strsplit("Used 2014 Toyota Camry", " ")[[1]][2]
[1] "2014"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
readr::parse_number(str1)
[1] 2014
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
 trimws(str1, whitespace = "\\D+")
[1] "2014"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "Used 2014 Toyota Camry"
```